# Cannot connect to wifi after suspend mode

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend

The problem occurs randomly. It says connection failed after few seconds and asks for wifi password if I click that message but entering the already saved password doesn’t help. I have to restart the modem to be able to reconnect. How can I solve this problem?

Ubuntu version 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal/shell/bash:

`ifconfig`
will tell you the currently running/active interfaces.

`sudo ifconfig <interface> down`
will shut down that interface.

`sudo ifconfig <interface> up`
will make it run again.

`sleep 1`
betweeen those will allow things to settle a bit.

Try it out, see if actually works for you. It might depend a bit on how things are set up.

Comment: Installed net-tools and ready to use it when it happens again.

Comment: Heh!? Strange, `dpkg --list | grep net-tools` returns nothing (to verify if it is preinstalled); I have NOT EVER installed that package and always had ifconfig available.

Comment: *The package is there, findable with e.g. `apt-file find /ifconfig` but it is not listed by `dpkg --list`*  (Ubuntu 20.04!)

Comment: Problem happened again today. I tried your solution but I couldn't connect again.